# Decision network example

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I am reading this example, but could you explain a little more.  I don't get the part where it says "then we Normalize"... I know

```
P(sun) * P(F=bad|sun)  = 0.7*0.2 = 0.14
P(rain)* P(F=bad|rain) = 0.3*0.9 = 0.27
```

But where do they get

```
W    P(W | F=bad)
-----------------
sun     0.34
rain    0.66
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
Example [from](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/fa10/slides/FA10%20cs188%20lecture%2018%20--%20decision%20diagrams%20%286PP%29.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Research has shown that people have difficulty reasoning in terms of probabilities but can do so accurately when presented with the same questions in terms of frequencies.  So, let's consider a closely related setting where the probabilities are expressed as numbers of occurrences:

- In 100 similar situations, it rained 30 times and was sunny 70 times.  This matches P(W=Sun) = 0.7 = 70/100 and P(W=Rain) = 0.3 = 30/100.
- From P(F=good|Sun) = 0.8 we compute that 0.8 * 70 = 56 times F will be "good" when W is "sun".  Likewise, from P(F=bad|Sun) = 0.2 we compute that 0.2 * 70 = 14 times F will be "bad" when W is "sun".
- From P(F=good|Rain) = 0.1 we compute that 0.1 * 30 = 3 times F will be "good" when W is "rain" and from P(F=bad|Rain) = 0.9 we compute that 0.9 * 30 = 27 times F will be "bad" when W is "rain".

If F is "bad", what can we say?  Well, this situation happened 14 + 27 = 41 times.  In 14/41 = 0.34 of those times W was "sun"; therefore, we expect P(W=Sun|F=Bad) = 0.34.  In the other 27/41 = 0.66 of those times W was "rain"; therefore, P(W=Rain|F=Bad) = 0.66.

Thus, "normalization" means *we focus only on those situations where the prior condition holds* (F=Bad in the example) *and rescale the probabilities to sum to unity* (as they must).

This is an archetypal example of [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) which in mathematical terms says that to compute conditional probabilities, **focus** and **rescale**.

Comment: do you know of any good free software to build decision networks? There is the Hydenet package in R but are you aware of anything else that may be better? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a straight forward analysis of Bayes Theorem.  Now Bayes Theorem reads:

$$P(H|F,I)=\frac{P(H|I)P(F|H,I)}{P(F|I)}$$

So in your example you have two "hypothesis" SUN and RAIN.  $F$ stands for the the forecast, and $I$ for the prior information (or assumptions).  The "I" has not been included explicitly in your question, but it is always there.  These create 2 equations,

$$P(SUN|F,I)=\frac{P(SUN|I)P(F|SUN,I)}{P(F|I)}$$
$$P(RAIN|F,I)=\frac{P(RAIN|I)P(F|RAIN,I)}{P(F|I)}$$

Now you have been given all probabilities except for the $P(F|I)$.  You can explicitly calculate this, but a quicker way is to get rid of it by taking the odds of SUN to RAIN.

$$\frac{P(SUN|F,I)}{P(RAIN|F,I)}=\frac{\frac{P(SUN|I)P(F|SUN,I)}{P(F|I)}}{\frac{P(RAIN|I)P(F|RAIN,I)}{P(F|I)}}=\frac{P(SUN|I)P(F|SUN,I)}{P(RAIN|I)P(F|RAIN,I)}$$

And this odds ratio is given by $\frac{0.14}{0.27}$.  And then you can use the exhaustiveness of the two hypothesis - because $$P(SUN|I)+P(RAIN|I)=1\rightarrow P(SUN|F,I)+P(RAIN|F,I)=1$$
$$\rightarrow P(RAIN|F,I)=1-P(SUN|F,I)$$

.  And you get:

$$\frac{P(SUN|F,I)}{1-P(SUN|F,I)}=\frac{0.14}{0.27}$$

And re-arranging for $P(SUN|F,I)$ gives:

$$P(SUN|F,I)=\frac{\frac{0.14}{0.27}}{1+\frac{0.14}{0.27}}=\frac{0.14}{0.41}=0.34$$